# Running count and count distinct on many rows (tens of thousands)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(events.event_id) AS total_events,
    COUNT(matches.fight_id) AS total_matches,
    COUNT(players.fighter_id) AS total_players,
    COUNT(DISTINCT events.organization) AS total_organizations,
    COUNT(DISTINCT players.country) AS total_countries
FROM 
    events, matches, players
```

These are table details:
Events = 21k
Players = 90k
Matches = 155k

All of those are uniques, so the query's first 3 things will be those numbers.  The other two values should be total_organizations, where the organization column is in the events (should return couple hundred), and total_countries should count distinct countries using country column in players table (also couple hundred).

All three of those ID columns are unique and indexed.

This query as it stands now takes forever.  I never even have patience to see it complete.  Is there a faster way of doing this?

Also, I need this to load these results on every page load, so should I just put this query in some hidden file, and set a cron job to run every midnight or something and populate a "totals" table or something so I can retrieve it from that table quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: What indexes have you defined on the tables, and why are you performing a JOIN across all three tables?

Comment: Just added it in the original post.  Right now, only those ID columns are indexed.

Comment: It that the whole query? it's doing a natural join IIRC

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a SQL noob.  I wasn't aware it does a join automatically if I try to count totals form multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the unnecessary join here; it's preventing most (if not all) of your indexes from being used.  You want three different queries:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(events.event_id) AS total_events,
    COUNT(DISTINCT events.organization) AS total_organizations
FROM 
    events;

SELECT 
    COUNT(matches.fight_id) AS total_matches
FROM 
    matches;

SELECT 
    COUNT(players.fighter_id) AS total_players,
    COUNT(DISTINCT players.country) AS total_countries
FROM 
    players;
```

This should go a long way to improving the performance of these queries.

Now, consider adding these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "events_organization" ON events (organization);
CREATE INDEX "players_country" ON events (country);
```

Compare the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` results before and after adding these indexes.  They might help and they might not.

---

Note that if you are using the InnoDB storage engine then all table rows will be visited anyway, to enforce transactional isolation.  In this case, indexes will only be used to determine which table rows to visit.  Since you are counting the entire table, the indexes will not be used at all.

If you are using MyISAM, which does not fully support MVCC, then `COUNT()` queries should be able to execute using only index cardinality, which will result in nearly instant results.  This is possible because transactions are not supported on MyISAM, which means that isolation becomes a non-issue.

So if you are using InnoDB, then you may wind up having to use a cronjob to create a cache of this data anyway.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you very much.  I ran those queries quickly to test and it loaded almost instantly. I'm using InnoDB, so I will go ahead and do the cron job method.  Thanks a bunch!  Learn something new every day!

Comment: If it loaded instantly, then you may not need to go the cron route.  It's something to keep in mind as your site grows; if these queries start dragging again, it may be time to profile (always use `EXPLAIN`!) and start caching.  (It might be worth inserting a few hundred thousand sample rows now and running the queries again to see how they perform on larger data sets.)  Premature optimization is the root of all evil... don't cache unless these queries become a bottleneck.

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll keep that in mind.  I have to play around with `EXPLAIN` a bit.  I'll start a new question if I need help with that.  Thanks again!